# How determine a packet protocol in libpcap?

Tags: c, packet, libpcap

I want to write a packet sniffer in `c`. Now my code can just count every packet is transmitted in network. I want it to count only `http` packets but I don't know how determine those in a packet.This is my code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char error[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct bpf_program *fp;
    char filter[] = "port 80";
    bpf_u_int32 network;
    pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_live(argv[1], BUFSIZ, 0, 1000, error);
    if (handle == NULL){
        printf("Error: %s\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter,0, network)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:%s\n", pcap_geterr(handle));
    }   

    if(pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:%s\n", pcap_geterr(handle));
        return 1;
    }

    pcap_loop(handle, atoi(argv[2]),callback, NULL );
    return 0;

}
```

my callback  function just count the number of packets.

Comment: Use the filter `tcp port 80 or tcp port 443` (the latter is if you also want `https`).

Comment: @Barmar I've used that but no packet will found in this way, I run a mini flask server and a client but no packet sniffer receives.

Comment: What port is the flask server bound to?

Comment: @GandhiGandhi I set the port of flask with the filter but it doesn't show anything

Comment: What happens when you run tcpdump with no filter, access the flask server (no other websites),  turn of the tcpdump quickly, then open the pcap file in wireshark and search for http packets.
That might show you the port number you're accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the http packets could be on any port (probably not unless you're testing a local web server), you could first isolate the payload of the packets. "Finding the Data Payload" at https://www.devdungeon.com/content/using-libpcap-c has an example about how to do that.

Then you could compare the first bytes of the data payload with any of the HTTP methods, or with the string "HTTP" to catch responses.